# Create a Javascript array from a PHP array

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, magento

I am having trouble converting from a PHP array to a Javascript array and then accessing the value. I have tried JSON encoding and decoding.

PHP:

```
$simpleArray= [];   
$childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
    ->getUsedProducts(null,$_product);   
foreach($childProducts as $child) { //cycle through simple products to find applicable
    $simpleArray[$child->getVendor()][$child->getColor()] = $child->getPrice();
    var_dump ($simpleArray);
}
```

Javascript:

```
var simpleArray = <?=json_encode($simpleArray)?>;
//..lots of unrelated code
for(var i=0; i < IDs.length; i++)
{   
    console.log(simpleArray);
    //which color id is selected 
    var colorSelected = $j("#attribute92 option:selected").val();
    console.log('Value of color selected is ' + colorSelected);
    $j('.details'+data[i].vendor_id).append('<li class="priceBlock">$'+simpleArray[i][colorSelected]+'</li>');
}
```

**Edit:** 
I have gotten rid of the simpleArrayJson declaration in the php and changed the first line of the javascript.

Comment: Don't json_decode it, you want it in json format. I'm not too familar with php, but what is `(array)` for in your second snippet, first line?

Comment: It was someone's suggestion in the PHP json_encode docs.. I have removed it. I now just have var simpleArray = <?=json_encode($simpleArray)?>; My issue now is accessing the value like it is an array: simpleArray[i][colorSelected]. All of the variables will be integers except $child->getPrice() which is a dollar value.

Comment: I don't understand why you are getting `function Array() { [native code] }` in your console.log. what browser are you testing with?

Comment: chrome... hmmm... ill look in firefox.

Comment: Oh sorry, that was before I put the json_encode in there. It logs an object. Again, now I just need to be able to access that value simpleArray[i][colorSelected]. Those variables in there will be integers.

Comment: What does the object look like?

Comment: I'll post a new question with a screen grab and then post the url here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723133/accessing-matrix-array-value-in-json-encoded-array

Answer (score 3):

The is no reason for you to `json_decode()` the value you are trying to output.  Just echo it directly:

```
var simpleArray = <?= $simpleArrayJson ?>;
```

This will output a javascript object literal.

Comment: var simpleArray = <?=json_encode($simpleArray)?>; with the rest of my code doesn't work

Comment: @CaitlinHavener That is because `simpleArray` is not a numerically indexed array.  It is an object literal. you either need to modify the data structure you encode to JSON, or modify how you work with it in javascript. Take a look at the structure that is output to understand better how you can work with it.

Comment: @CaitlinHavener OK back to basics I guess.  Do you know the difference between a numerically indexed array and an associative array in PHP?  In javascript, do you know the difference between a numerically indexed array and an object (the closest thing to associative array in javascript)?

Comment: Do you understand that in your PHP, you appear to be building an associative array (unless `$child->getVendor()` returns integer values)?  Further when you use `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` flag with `json_encode()`, even if you have a numerically indexed array, that you would cause an object to be formed in your JSON serialization.  You then try to access `simpleArray` in JS using numeric indexes, which there is no way you have created.  You have a javascript object, you need to access it as such. Alternatively, you can build a true 0-based numerically indexed array in PHP and not use JSON_FORCE_OBJECT

Comment: Ahhh.. it is numerically indexed array in the PHP. The $child->getVendor() and $child->getColor() values are integers. I have removed the force object, but it is still a json object. I need to be able to access the value of example simpleArray[4][5] which would be 1.50 for example. I'm not sure how to do that. Under Edit, you can see what I changed.

Comment: Your array needs to be 0-based and sequential in order to be JSON-encoded with array notation (i.e. made into an array in JS).  If you are using autoincrement ID values derived from a database, you are likely not going to meet this criteria, and it will be encoded as an object.  My guess is you will need to access the data as an object. This is ok in that JS allows array-like access to objects, you will just need to understand that the objecy keys will be integer string, not actual integers. So you would need to access like `simpleArray['4']['5']`

Answer (score 0):

try a for in loop.

```
for( item in data ) {
    console.log(data[item]);
}
```

this is because json has keys that match the indexes of the array that was json_encoded, instead of necessarily 0->n indexes.

**Edit** thanks to comments changed `data.item` to `data[item]`

Comment: for( item in simpleArray ) {
     console.log(simpleArray.item);
     
}

Comment: Shouldn't that be `console.log(item)` or `console.log(data[item])`? `console.log(data.item)` is wrong unless `data` has an `item` property.

Answer (score 0):

Remove from the php.

```
$simpleArrayJson=json_encode($simpleArray, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

here you are converting the php array into a json string.

Change in the javascript

```
var simpleArray = <?= json_encode($simpleArray, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT); ?>;
```

Here you are just outputting the sting. previously you where doing this

```
var simpleArray = <?=(array) json_decode($simpleArrayJson)?>
```

which after json_decode was returning an array, which you where casting to an array which then was cast to a string by the `<?=`  so what ended up going to your browser was something like:

```
var simpleArray = Array;
```