# Accessing Matrix Array Value in Json_encoded Array

Tags: php, jquery

I have a php array that I assigned to a javascript variable with json_encode. The php array is numerical not associative.

Example: simpleArray[5][7]=1.50. I need to be able to access the 1.50 after the array has been json_encoded based on the index values.

PHP:

```
$simpleArray= [];   

foreach($childProducts as $child) { //cycle through simple products to find applicable
    $simpleArray[$child->getVendor()][$child->getColor()] = $child->getPrice();
    var_dump ($simpleArray);
}
```

Javascript:

```
var simpleArray = <?=json_encode($simpleArray)?>;
//..lots of unrelated code
for(var i=0; i < IDs.length; i++)
{   
    console.log(simpleArray);//see the picture of me below
    var colorSelected = $j("#attribute92 option:selected").val(); //integer value

    $j('.details'+data[i].vendor_id).append('<li class="priceBlock">$'+simpleArray[i][colorSelected]+'</li>');
}
```

Console.log(simpleArray):

[image]

Comment: What's `IDs` and `data`? Your `simpleArray[i][colorSelected]` is right, provided `i` (taken from `IDs.length`) is a value in the first dimension.

Comment: "need to access"? Why not use the original array? $simpleArray[5][7]. json is a data encapsulation/transport format. it's nothing something you should EVER be attempting to "access".

Comment: I need to access the php array within the javascript because it's dynamic on the page. I just took a clip of this code. Before it is a ajax request, hence the data, but it shouldn't be applicable to this issue.

Comment: Your object doesn't have keys at `0` `1` and `2`, you'll get an error on `simpleArray[i][colorSelected]` because i first equals 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are likely trying to access values that don't exist in your object:

```
simpleArray[i][colorSelected]
```

Based on your for loop definition, you can have `i` values of 0, 1, 2 which don't exist in the object shown (which has properties at keys: 3,4,5). Also your for loop has no relation at all to the number of items in your object, which I am not sure is intended.

Also, `colorSelected` derives it's value from a call to `val()` which returns a string you you probably want to change the line where it is defined to:

```
var colorSelected = parseInt($j("#attribute92 option:selected").val());
```

This will make it an integer value.

Comment: Object keys are `toString()`'d anyway, so `parseInt` or no-`parseInt` should make a difference (http://jsfiddle.net/SEaFy/).